# Why i get this error when i try to run this command line?

Tags: symfony

When I try to run:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException' with message 
>   'No identifier/primary key specified for Entity 'OC\PlatformeBundle\Entity\Advert'.
>   Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.'

Advert.php:

```
namespace OC\PlatformBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Advert
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="advert")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="OC\PlatformBundle\Repository\AdvertRepository")
 */
class Advert
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="published", type="boolean")
    */
    private $published = true;

    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="author", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
     */
    private $content;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     *
     * @return Advert
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     *
     * @return Advert
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set author
     *
     * @param string $author
     *
     * @return Advert
     */
    public function setAuthor($author)
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get author
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param string $content
     *
     * @return Advert
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
    // Par défaut, la date de l'annonce est la date d'aujourd'hui
    $this->date = new \Datetime();
    }

    /**
     * Set published
     *
     * @param boolean $published
     *
     * @return Advert
     */
    public function setPublished($published)
    {
        $this->published = $published;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get published
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getPublished()
    {
        return $this->published;
    }
}
```

Comment: You must add `@ORM\Id` to your `$id` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's because you didn't specify the primary key on id column.

Just fix as this

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;
```

:)